# How to write down the state after a measurement if the result was not recorded?

Tags: quantum-information, measurements, quantum-states

I measure the spin of an unknown qubit in the computational basis but I do not record what the outcome of the measurement was. How should I now describe the state?

If it is described as a maximally mixed state, it neglects the knowledge of the basis. In particular, remeasuring in the computational basis has no effect on the state and this isn't true for a maximally mixed state. How do I trace out the measurement result but acknowledge the fact that I know the basis of measurement?

This question is inspired by https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05472 but I'm not completely sure if my problem is equivalent to the one posed there.

Comment: If you know the initial state, you know the probabilities, so the state isn't maximally mixed.

Comment: I assumed an unknown qubit. I have made this point explicit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post-measurement state is
$$
\rho'= \sum_{i} |i\rangle\langle i|\rho|i\rangle\langle i|\ ,
$$
or differently speaking, $\rho'$ is the diagonal of $\rho$.